# Why my website loading time is too big on gtmetrix?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, gtmetrix

I can't understand why I visiting my site in couple a seconds, but when I check it on the gtmetrix it says 90+ seconds to load the page. Can someone help me? my site is : http://walshdidthat.com/

Comment: 1. There are errors in the console which might be the reason gtmetrix fails 2. gtmetrix history shows the page has been fast before March 03 so investigate the changes you've made.

Comment: the site was broken back that time. So we decide to move it to another hoster and setup an cloudfront for it. And now the site works like it should, but in testing tools like gtmetrix we have 90+sec loading and we don't know why.

Comment: Please, can you tell me what problem I need to solve?with this errors

Answer (score 0):

When you run the page on WebPageTest you can see that the page requests some audio files that take a very long time to load. This is likely the cause of the long load times that gtmetrix is reporting.

I don't know much about how audio files are loaded, but you need to request these files in a way that does not block the [critical rendering path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/) of the page.

[image: webpagetest results]

Comment: Its a video files...Do you know how to make them loading faster, etc? Now they located at amazon cdn, but when I change links to origin godaddy hosting - the video lag as hell